# CollectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath not called if UIView animation is running on the cells

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uicollectionviewcell, uiviewanimation

I have a collection view displaying incoming calls. With each entry, the new cell starts animating and it should stop once the necessary action is taken on the call. However, did select method doesn't get triggered while this UIView animation on repeat is playing. Any ideas on how to go ahead with this? Thank you.

Comment: is user interaction enabled on said view?

Comment: @Miknash thank you for your response! figured it out as below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution. I had forgotten to add UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction on the UIView animation options! In case someone else would have the same problem as me, here is my solution!

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{

        weakSelf.view.backgroundColor = //;

    }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) { 
    }];
```